# calling ajax function in ejs right above invocation

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, ejs

I am trying to call an ajax function in ejs but i keep getting an error and am unsure why. I have looked at other posts on this but can not seem to find the answer. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. getLikesCountEjs(posts.id, "getAllLikesCount")

```
<%
 function getLikesCountEjs(idOfPost, type) {
     var finalResult;
     $.ajax({
       url: "/home",
       method: "POST",
       async: false,
       dataType: "json",
       data: { type: type, idOfPost: idOfPost},
       success: function (r) {
        if(r.likes !== undefined)  { finalResult = r.likes; }
        if(r.color !== undefined) { finalResult = r.color; }
       },
       error: function (xhr, status, error) {
         var errorMessage = xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText;
         console.log(errorMessage);
       },
     });
   return finalResult;
   }
  %>
                                  
  <% myTimeLine.value.forEach(function(posts) { %>
  <a href="#" class="link-black text-sm interactSetLikesTimeLine" id = "setLikes-<%=posts.id%>"
  ><i class="far fa-thumbs-up mr-1"> Likes <%= getLikesCountEjs(posts.id, "getAllLikesCount") %> </i> 
  <% }) %>
```

Comment: `getting an error` - should we guess what the error is? or can you share that information?

Comment: Im not sure, im getting a 500 error.  if I remove the invocation it goes away though.

Comment: a 500 error means there's a problem *on the server* - so, that code won't help find the problem

Comment: yeah but...the code works fine on the server because I'm running this same exact script in my javascripts with same functions and everything.

Comment: your server is sending a `500` response ... why?

Comment: is there a tool to tell. npm? it just says 500 error